# Find null or value(s)

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Join to a table that stores multivalue information
Need to query for null or value(s)
Currently do it with a union
First get the null with an outer join
Second union to get the values 
Is there a better approach?

```
select [docSVsys].[sID] 
  from [docSVsys] with (nolock) 
  left outer join [docEnum1] as [jointable] with (nolock) 
    on [jointable].[enumID] = '142' 
   and [jointable].[sID] =  [docSVsys].[sID] 
 where [jointable].[sID] is null 
Union 
Select distinct([Table].[sID]) 
  From  [DocEnum1] as [Table] with (nolock) 
 Where  1 = 1
   And  [Table].[enumID] = '142' 
   and  [Table].[valueID] in (1,2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select distinct
case
    when [jointable].[valueID] in (1,2) then [jointable].[sID]
    else [docSVsys].[sID] 
end
from [docSVsys] with (nolock) 
left outer join [docEnum1] as [jointable] with (nolock) 
    on [jointable].[enumID] = '142' 
    and [jointable].[sID] =  [docSVsys].[sID] 
where [jointable].[sID] is null or [jointable].[valueID] in (1,2)
```

Tell me if it's OK

Comment: Problem there is can get duplicate sID (e.g. has both valueID 1 and 2) and the way I use this is a bigger query I need only 1

Comment: @Blam: You're right. I've update my answer, I've added distinct keyword. Tell me if it's ok ;)

Comment: It does not need the case.  Can just select distinct [docSVsys].[sID]

Comment: I'm not sure because in your query (after UNION) you'll get id by other table.

Comment: One of the join conditions is [jointable].[sID] = [docSVsys].[sID].  If select [docSVsys].[sID] breaks it then the query was wrong in the first place.